# Regular expression to replace

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I heard it's possible to use regular expression to replace. I have following scenario where I would like to remove index number semicolon and pound sign.

```
(Index Number;#)
```

For example `521;#SouthWest Region`
after expression it should be `Southwest Region`

I tried many variation (`(?<=^.*?;).*`  OR  `^.*?;` ) but not working.

Comment: What language are you using? Could you post what have you tried?

Comment: c#, .net, cause I am using Nintex Workflow

Comment: If this is related to SharePoint, consider using [`SPFieldLookupValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldlookupvalue.aspx) - there are also variants for multiple values (SPFieldLookupValueCollection), and client-side (or remote) parsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  Regex.Replace("521;#SouthWest Region", @"\d+;#", "");
  // results SouthWest Region
```

Comment: They are all dynamic. 521 and the regions. seperated by ;#

Comment: `\d+` means 1 or more digits, then a ';' character and a '#' character, seems to be correct shawn, just fill in a few strings instead of the first string and see if they go right, if fail, edit your question to match.

Comment: Sir, I tried above but it did not work in Nintex workflow which is supposed to be .net based. Is the regex different for xml?

Comment: Actually, Nintex uses Microsoft .NET regular expression. I just confirmed that.

Comment: @Shiplu: I am sorry, your code worked. I just to tweak it. Here is the modified version that worked. \d+;# that's all I had to use. THANKS A LOT.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void Replace()
{
    var myString = "(In£dex N#£umber;#)";
    var replacement = String.Empty;
    var regExPattern = @"\d|[#£;]";
    var regEx = new Regex(regExPattern);
    var result = regEx.Replace(myString, replacement);

    Console.WriteLine("The replaced string: {0}", result); 
}
```

Edit: Ooops, sorry, i think I missunderstod your question.

Edit 2: Replace the above code with: `var regExPattern = @"\d|[#£;]";`

Comment: Thanks for supplying the snippet but I think Nintex just accepts expression syntax not a function.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+Shift+H Find what: `(.*)\;\#{.*}` Replace with: `\1`

Comment: Are you referring to VS Studio? If yes, that wont work. Nintex will accept one line .net regular expression.

Comment: I thought you meant replace from Visual Studio :(